# Java printf why doesnt it format correctly in my method?

Tags: java, methods, call, printf

When I call the method

```
public static void print(){
    System.out.printf("%10s", "Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average\n");
}
```

It does not format correctly(it doesn't indent at all) can someone explain to me why.

I want the output to be

```
     Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average
```

^^10 indented spaces

Comment: Why do you think it should indent? Maybe use `\t` for indents?

Comment: What purpose are you trying to achieve...can you add what is the expected output ?

Comment: If you want 10 spaces at the beginning of what you print, just add 10 spaces at the beginning of what you print : `"          Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average\n"`

Answer (score 4):

Your `printf` argument is 29 characters long but you're only allowing for a 10 character offset so no indentation is produced. Therefore you need an a format specifier width of 10 + 29 (full string)

```
System.out.printf("%39s", "Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average\n");
```

Simpler still use a single `Formatter` `String` (and use the platform independent newline specifier - `%n`)

```
System.out.printf("%10sTest 1 Test 2 Test 3 Average%n", " ");
```

Read the [Formatter javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more

Answer (score 0):

I think that by "indenting" you mean padding, because printf is not meant for indentation. The code you provided won't add any spaces because the string is longer than 10 characters. Besides, %10s is meant to add spaces *after* a string to match the size of 10 characters (in the given example).

If you wanted to pad the string with spaces *before*, you'd write:

System.out.printf("% 10s", ...)

In this case, it would pad the string with spaces to match 10 characters.